# Is an object located within the field of view of a robot?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, self-learning

**Background:**

Assume we have three robots as given in the figure.

The robot in the middle has camera in the front and in the back.

How to calculate whether:

1. the grey robot is in the field-of-view (FOV) -- marked with orange line -- of the front camera of the green robot?
2. the blue robot is in the FOV of the back camera of the green robot?

[image]

---

**Current knowledge:**

- Ignore the rectangular form of the robots, (if that helps).
- Coordinates of all of the robots are known, they are given as `Coord(x,y)`
- The length of the maximum range of the FOV is `100`m --> that's the length of the orange lines.
- The half-angle of the FOV is 45 degrees (the angle between the blue arrow and the orange line)
- The coordinate system used to obtain the heading of the robots ranges between `-pi` and `pi` (as given in the figure below). So the heading for green robot is `-pi`

[image]

---

**What has been done so far:**

So far, I tried to adapt some implementation to my case but I am not sure whether it is correct, so I need validation on that front, or comments from your side.

```
double distanceFromGreen2Grey = greenPos.distance(greyPos);

// Angles
double greenHeading = r0->getHeading();
double greyHeading = r1->getHeading();

// Calculate normalized vectors
Coord vectorFromGreen2Grey = (greyPos - greenPos) / distanceFromGreen2Grey;
Coord greenHeadingVector = Coord(cos(greenHeading), sin(greenHeading)) * 1; // <-- 1 used for front
Coord greyHeadingVector = Coord(cos(greyHeading), sin(greyHeading)) * -1; //  <-- -1 used for back

// why use acos here?
double angle = acos(vectorFromGreen2Grey * greenHeadingVector) / M_PI * 180;
double bearing = acos(vectorFromGreen2Grey * greyHeadingVector) / M_PI * 180;


bool inRange = distanceFromGreen2Grey <= 100;
bool inAngle = (vectorFromGreen2Grey * greyHeadingVector) > cos(M_PI/4);
bool inAngle2 = ((greyPos - greenPos)/cos(M_PI/4))*greyHeadingVector >= distanceFromGreen2Grey;
bool withinBearing = (vectorFromGreen2Grey * greenHeadingVector) < 0;
```

---

**Extra question:** How to find the end points for the orange lines so I can draw lines from the coords of the green robot to the endpoints of the orange lines. The FOV lines should move as the robots move too.

---

**References:**

I found other questions on SE which address this topic, but they don't use `acos` as in my code.

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542821/how-to-calculate-if-something-lies-in-someones-field-of-vision mentions something like `velocity vector` but I could not map that to my case.
2. Something similar has also been asked here: [How do I plot a 'field of view' in 2D space and find if a certain point lies within the space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921033/how-do-i-plot-a-field-of-view-in-2d-space-and-find-if-a-certain-point-lies-wit)

Comment: The robot is in the field of view so long as the coordinate of the robot is in the bounds of the triangle formed by the orange line. How can you determine if a point is inside a triangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost exactly the same problem as [one of the ones you cite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921033/how-do-i-plot-a-field-of-view-in-2d-space-and-find-if-a-certain-point-lies-wit). The only interesting difference is that instead of having to determine the camera’s facing from the endpoints of a line segment (robot arm section), you already know it. In addition, the field of view has a limited range, but that’s not a significant complication, nor is the addition of a rear-facing camera.

To review, in [the cited question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921033/how-do-i-plot-a-field-of-view-in-2d-space-and-find-if-a-certain-point-lies-wit) the target point is in the field of view if $$(Q-P_4)\cdot(P_4-P_3)\ge\|Q-P_4\|\,\|P_4-P_3\|\cos\theta,\tag{*}$$ where $Q$ is the target point, $P_4$ is the location of the camera, $P_3$ the other end of the robot arm segment, and $\theta$ is the half-angle of the field of view. Since we don’t have a robot arm holding the camera, let’s just call the camera’s location $P$ and let’s call the green robot’s heading $\phi$. $P_4-P_3$ gives us a vector in the direction of the camera’s facing, so assuming that the camera is facing directly forward, we can use the unit vector in that direction: $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$. Using a unit vector also eliminates the factor of $\|P_4-P_3\|$, since that came from normalizing the camera-direction vector. For this camera, $\theta=\pi/4$, so $\cos\theta=1/\sqrt2$. Putting this all together and moving the $\sqrt2$ to the left side, we get $$\sqrt2\,(Q-P)\cdot(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)\ge\|Q-P\|.\tag{1}$$ The range check is, of course, $\|Q-P\|\le100$. To check the rear view, just reverse the unit facing vector to $(-\cos\phi,-\sin\phi)$.

Since you have two conditions that both involve testing against $\|Q-P\|$, it’s more efficient to test the one that requires less work first. I suggest testing the square of the distance first, i.e., $\|Q-P\|=(Q-P)\cdot(Q-P)\le100^2$, to avoid computing a square root if the target is too far away. I can’t tell from your code snippet whether or not that’s practical, though. If the target isn’t too far away, then you can go ahead and take the square root and compute the rest of test (1).

Looking at your code snippet, it looks like you’re trying to do something along these lines, but there’s an error. The gray robot’s heading is wrong thing to use for `inAngle`. The target’s heading is irrelevant to deciding whether or not it’s visible. In the original formula, $(P_4-P_3)/\|P_4-P_3\|$ corresponds to your `greenHeadingVector` instead. Observe, too, that at least for this computation, there’s no need to normalize `vectorFromGreen2Grey`. That saves you a division operation. Of course, if you need the normalized value for other things, it’s almost certainly more efficient to normalize once, as you do.

Comment: can you be a bit more verbose about how did you derive **(1)** and what does it represent in terms of points in plane, a drawing would surely help. Additionally, what kind of coordinate system do you assume? Or, does the coordinate system matter at all, or the calculations are universal across any angle coordinate system?

Comment: @KristofTak Set $P_4-P_3=(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ in $(*)$ and divide both sides by $\cos\theta=\cos{\pi/4}=1/\sqrt{2}$. A Cartesian coordinate system is assumed, with angles measured consistently with it, i.e., the angle between the positive $x$-axis and positive $y$-axis is positive. You can find the derivation of $(*)$ in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1921066/265466), which appears to me you’ve used in your code. I’ve rearranged the inequality so that it fits more neatly on a single line.

Comment: @KristofTak The formula is universal insofar as it works for any facing and positions of the robots within that coordinate system.

Comment: sorry for coming back to this. This is importnat to clarify, the coordinate system you assume is the "polar" one, as here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Polar_graph_paper.svg/250px-Polar_graph_paper.svg.png right?

Comment: @KristofTak No. This assumes a Cartesian coordinate system with angles measured counterclockwise. Doing this in a polar coordinate system centered on the green robot would be trivial.

Comment: here we go ?!?: http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/functions/functions31.gif

Comment: @KristofTak Looks OK to me. What is it that you’re unsure of?

Comment: in my code, the relative angle between the robots changes as they move in circular fashion although their movement pattern is fixed around that circle. there I would expect fixed relative angle. I suspect that could be due to the difference inc coordinate systems. My angles are given as in the photo above (in my original question post). Due to this, the calculation from above says that the `grey` fell out of the FOV of `green`, which should not be the case... any input?

Comment: @KristofTak Not without seeing your code. You did fix the bug that I pointed out, didn’t you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46432/discussion-between-kristof-tak-and-amd).

Answer (score -1):

Write the equation of the orange lines.
[image]