# How to check object is in my view or not?

Tags: vectors

I tried to solve this using plane concept. I have **angle of fov**, **my position**, **my front vector**. So, normalize front vector, vectorV(my pos - object pos) dot product these two, if the result is positive, it is in front of me. The problem is that I'm not sure how to deal with the angle. Any advise will be appreciated. Thanks for your help :D

[image]

Comment: Please don't link offsite. Include the necessary information in the body of your question, instead.

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry about that, was my fault. I changed it

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1946639/265466.

Comment: @amd thanks for the link :D